# how can i attach file back to input type file field

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

My application is developed in asp.net c#. I have a form to update data with image, this is working fine  and record is getting saved in database perfectly. In a scenario where my form is in edit mode, i am retrieving record from database using ajax with JSON response and binding all input fields with JSON response. The problem here is i have a IMAGE location in response (~/assets/gallery/popup/image.jpg), how can i **assign it back to input file** type field with **image preview**, to show previously selected image. Suggest me some ideas or alternative approach.

If assigning file location back to field is not possible, then how should i proceed with this, to show previously selected image

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: thanks for response Arun,, how to deal with this ?

Comment: If you just need a preview, there are ways to do that on the clientside, but setting the value of the file input back to the fake filepath doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

Just send back the image URL to the client as a callback. Then use javascript to load the image by adding this tag:

```
$("#previewDivId").append("<img src='" + ImageURL + "' />");
```

Remember to replace previewDivId and ImageURL in the above code.